# Pandas - subtracting 2 variable after group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following Pandas "code"

```
df=pd.read_csv('option_data.csv')

In [30]:

df.head(9)
​
Out[30]:
     S    date    E   D     V
0  IBM  1/2/2008  1  10  0.1718
1  IBM  1/2/2008  1  50  0.2144
2  IBM  1/2/2008  1  90  0.2733
3  IBM  1/3/2008  1  10  0.1692
4  IBM  1/3/2008  1  50  0.2081
5  IBM  1/3/2008  1  90  0.2634
6  IBM  1/4/2008  1  10  0.1844
7  IBM  1/4/2008  1  50  0.2283
8  IBM  1/4/2008  1  90  0.2779
```

I wish to create a variable that is the spread between V when D = 90 and V when D=10.  The first value would be (.2733 - .1718) = .1015.  Example below:

```
S   date        E   D      V    Skew
IBM 1/2/2008    1   10  0.1718  
IBM 1/2/2008    1   50  0.2144  0.1015
IBM 1/2/2008    1   90  0.2733  
IBM 1/3/2008    1   10  0.1692  
IBM 1/3/2008    1   50  0.2081  0.0942
IBM 1/3/2008    1   90  0.2634  
IBM 1/4/2008    1   10  0.1844  
IBM 1/4/2008    1   50  0.2283  0.0935
IBM 1/4/2008    1   90  0.2779
```

the last variable is the change in the "Skew variable" as a percent of V when D=50 for the first Skew number.  So, (0.0942-0.1015)/0.2144 = -.03405

```
S   date        E   D   V       Skew    pct_change_Skew
IBM 1/2/2008    1   10  0.1718      
IBM 1/2/2008    1   50  0.2144  0.1015  
IBM 1/2/2008    1   90  0.2733      
IBM 1/3/2008    1   10  0.1692      
IBM 1/3/2008    1   50  0.2081  0.0942  -0.03405
IBM 1/3/2008    1   90  0.2634      
IBM 1/4/2008    1   10  0.1844      
IBM 1/4/2008    1   50  0.2283  0.0935  -0.00001
IBM 1/4/2008    1   90  0.2779
```

My setup is  below:

```
df = df.groupby(['S','date','E']).apply(????)
```

I need to perform the groupby as there are many S (symbols), dates and E values.

Ideally I would have the new variables populate each row as such:

```
S   date        E   D     V      Skew   pct_change_Skew
IBM 1/2/2008    1   10  0.1718  0.1015  
IBM 1/2/2008    1   50  0.2144  0.1015  
IBM 1/2/2008    1   90  0.2733  0.1015  
IBM 1/3/2008    1   10  0.1692  0.0942  -0.03405
IBM 1/3/2008    1   50  0.2081  0.0942  -0.03405
IBM 1/3/2008    1   90  0.2634  0.0942  -0.03405
IBM 1/4/2008    1   10  0.1844  0.0935  -0.00001
IBM 1/4/2008    1   50  0.2283  0.0935  -0.00001
IBM 1/4/2008    1   90  0.2779  0.0935  -0.00001
```

If I can be so bold as to ask for a pandas as well as a python "straight" code example, it would help my learning curve.  Thank you very much for any assistance in this.

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the new 'Skew' column, you can do a `groupby` and define your customized `apply` function. To calculate pct_change, you can use the `.shift()` operator.

```
import pandas as pd

df

Out[31]: 
     S      date  E   D       V
0  IBM  1/2/2008  1  10  0.1718
1  IBM  1/2/2008  1  50  0.2144
2  IBM  1/2/2008  1  90  0.2733
3  IBM  1/3/2008  1  10  0.1692
4  IBM  1/3/2008  1  50  0.2081
5  IBM  1/3/2008  1  90  0.2634
6  IBM  1/4/2008  1  10  0.1844
7  IBM  1/4/2008  1  50  0.2283
8  IBM  1/4/2008  1  90  0.2779

def calculate_skew(group):
    group['Skew'] = group.loc[group.D==90, 'V'].values[0] - group.loc[group.D==10, 'V'].values[0]
    return group
# get the new Skew column
df = df.groupby(['S','date']).apply(calculate_skew)
# calculate pct_change
df['Skew_lag3'] = df.Skew.shift(3)
df['Skew_pct_change'] = (df.Skew - df.Skew_lag3)/df.Skew_lag3

Out[33]: 
     S      date  E   D       V    Skew  Skew_lag3  Skew_pct_change
0  IBM  1/2/2008  1  10  0.1718  0.1015        NaN              NaN
1  IBM  1/2/2008  1  50  0.2144  0.1015        NaN              NaN
2  IBM  1/2/2008  1  90  0.2733  0.1015        NaN              NaN
3  IBM  1/3/2008  1  10  0.1692  0.0942     0.1015          -0.0719
4  IBM  1/3/2008  1  50  0.2081  0.0942     0.1015          -0.0719
5  IBM  1/3/2008  1  90  0.2634  0.0942     0.1015          -0.0719
6  IBM  1/4/2008  1  10  0.1844  0.0935     0.0942          -0.0074
7  IBM  1/4/2008  1  50  0.2283  0.0935     0.0942          -0.0074
8  IBM  1/4/2008  1  90  0.2779  0.0935     0.0942          -0.0074
```

Comment: Thanks Jianxun, creating a "shift" variable did the trick!!!  The only comment is that I wanted the pct change in skew to be as a percent of the ATM (D=50) rather than the "Skew_lag3" variable.  I created a V_lag3 variable and used that . . .worked perfectly!!!  thanks again!

Comment: Jianxun Li,  how would I build in a "error check" if I had a particular day where I was missing one of the 3 needed D values . . .for example, if I were missing the D=10 value at index location 6 I still get an result but it is not correct.  If it is missing I want to move to the next day and not look to the previous "full D" day but rather treat that good day (following the day with missing data) like it was the first day so that I was not looking at skew changes over multiple days (as i could be missing D data for many days in a row)